# Error when call angular $http - "Provider must return a value from $get factory method."

Tags: angularjs

i'm using ionic framework for mobile apps which work with angular js ..
i had error when calling ajax data (factory,controller) ..

when reload it gives me this error "Provider 'stations' must return a value from $get factory method."

some of code :

```
enter cod  //services.js
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('stations',['$http',function($http){ 
var stations = [];               $http.get(base_url+'api/stations/uid/'+uu_id).success(function(response){
            stations = response;     
            return stations;
      });  
}])
//controllers.js
.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope', 'stations', function($scope,stations){ 
    $scope.stations = [];    
    stations.success(function(data){ 
        $scope.stations = data;
    });     
}])e here
```

thanks for help :) ....

Comment: don't your data are under `response.data` instead of `response` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error >> all what i forgot to do is to return data from http get in factory services.js >>

```
 .factory('stations',['$http',function($http){ 
    var stations = [];
    return $http.get(base_url+'api/stations/uid/'+uu_id).success(function(response){
            stations = response;     
            return stations;
    });  
}])
```

Comment: As long as you are not providing any transformations for **response** you can just return `$http.get(base_url+'api/stations/uid/'+uu_id)` from factory. Nothing more ...